# Столкновения трёхмерных объектов

Tags: xna-4, геометрия, алгоритм, c#

Как определить столкновение двух трёхмерных фигур в пространстве? Не столь важен язык или сам способ представления объекта, как алгоритм и соответствующий код (конечно, лучше используя csharp и библиотеки XNA).

Просьба не предлагать алгоритмы типа: вписать оба объекта в сферу и проверять столкновения сфер - это самое простое решение, которое в моей ситуации не учитывает специфику трёхмерных объектов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите [коллекцию алгоритмов](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html). Вот [статейка](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf) оттуда. Идея этого метода определения, пересекаются ли выпуклые фигуры: Если существует прямая, проекции фигур на которую (отрезки, значит) не пересекаются, то фигуры не пересекаются.

Comment: а если фигура не выпуклая?

Comment: прверить выпуклую оболочку, потом проверять нужные выпуклые части

Comment: а если проверку необходимо производить очень часто, то по каждой фигуре строить выпуклую оболочку? слишком долго. может есть что-нибудь эффективней?

Comment: ну ясное дело, что оболочки можно строить один раз, более того, оболочки не над тучей точек, а над вершинами - это эффективнее, прочие эффективности предложены в других ответах, описанные сферы, прямоугольники и проч. Мой ответ в основном даёт источник материалов и пример алгоритма. Список алгоритмов большой и структурированный, есть статьи и исходный код. К тому же вопрос был без особых деталей

Comment: в любом случае Ваша информация оказалась полезной. +1

Comment: ну вот хороший ответ @ArtFeel, дающий туториал, можно сказать, также привёл к ссылке http://www.gamedev.ru/code/articles/?id=4195 , где рекомендуют метод разделяющих осей, который я предложил

Answer (score 2):

На алголисте много по этой теме.
http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/index.php

В частности вот по пересечению.
http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/intersect/

Answer (score 2):

Сферы в любом случае придется проверять, и только если сферы пересеклись, идти глубже и проверять пересечения треугольников.

Вот посмотрите эту статью, там в конце есть код как очень просто добавить обработку колизий к моделям. [Пишем игры для Windows Phone](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/gdev/90768/)

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что хочется посоветовать - никогда не скрещивать физику и графику. Визуальные объекты - одно, обнаружение столкновений - совсем другое.

По сабжу, лучше воспользоваться одним из открытых физических движков. ODE, к примеру, Bullet, Newtone. Они позволяют не только обнаружить факт пересечения объектов(причём, делают это гораздо быстрее рукописных решений), но и отреагировать на него(в смысле, объекты будут вести себя как настоящие).

Answer (score 1):

Ну, не хотите в сферу - впишите в прямоугольный параллелепипед (куб, например), причем ориентированный по глобальным осям координат... :)  - В принципе это как раз первый шаг, так как проще всего проверить на столкновение объекты такого рода (сфера потребует умножений - расчет расстояния, параллелепипед - только сравнения координат) и уже если пересечение параллелепипедов (bounding box) зафиксировано, то анализировать на столкновение собственно сложные многогранные объекты... По меньшей мере это оптимизация.

Если хотите хорошо разобраться в тематике (3D движки), советую книгу **David H. Eberly**, *3d Game Engine Design: A Practical Approach to Real-time Computer Graphics*. В книге рассмотрены все аспекты создания 3d движков, включая поиск пересечений... PDF можно найти на торрент-трекерах или в сети ed2k.