# Определение столкновений

Tags: разработка-игр, 3d

Как обычно реализуется определение столкновений в 3D играх, например, персонажа с поверхностью, по которой он ходит с учётом гравитации (это может быть либо камера от первого лица, либо управление персонажем от третьего лица)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14368/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) был.

Достаточно простым и часто достаточным является вписывание объектов в прямоугольные параллелепипеды со сторонами, перпендикулярными осям координат. В таком случае проверка столкновений тривиальна: если сторона одного лежит между двумя другими, то есть столкновение. Данный приём используется в том же Minecraft'е.